# tabbing not working on custom CSS checkbox

Tags: jquery, css

If I start tabbing through the form input fields I have just noticed that it skips my custom CSS checkbox which has the following code:

```
.voucher_form input[type="text"],
.voucher_form input[type="email"]{
.box-sizing;
border-radius:14px;
background-color:#fff;
padding:6px 5px;
width:inherit;
border:0;
-moz-box-shadow:inset -1px 1px 3px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset -1px 1px 3px #888;
box-shadow:inset -1px 1px 3px #888;
margin-top:6px;
font-size:16px;
color:#6f6f6f;
}

.voucher_form input[type="checkbox"]{
padding:0;
}

.voucher_form  input[type="checkbox"] {
display:none;
}

.voucher_form  input[type="checkbox"] + label span{
display:inline-block;
width:20px;
height:20px;
margin:-2px 4px 0 0;
vertical-align:middle;
cursor:pointer;
}

.voucher_form  input[type="checkbox"] + label span{
background:url("../image/radio.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.voucher_form  input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
background:url("../image/radio.png") 0 -20px no-repeat;
}
```

Is it because of the following set to 'display:none'?

```
 .voucher_form  input[type="checkbox"] {
   display:none;
 }
```

If so is there a way fixing this problem?

Comment: you shouldn't really use `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` for inputs as some browsers will treat them as not being on the page - try absolutely positioning it off the screen instead

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works but having the input off the screen you can't see it..

Comment: surely if you use display:none, you can't see it